# what does that mean by saying "a sample having 2 (or more) observations"? does the observation mean possible outcome from an experiment?

Tags: sampling, sample

Say, I am drawing balls.
"drawing 2 balls from 3(labeled numbers from 1 to 3) with replacement" is an experiment.

perform this experiment could result 9 possible outcomes.
here is the list

```
[[1, 1],
[1, 2],
[1, 3],
[2, 1],
[2, 2],
[2, 3],
[3, 1],
[3, 2],
[3, 3]]
```

perform this experiment one time (a trial) could produce one outcome of those 9.

by performing this experiment one time, I got, say, a [3, 1], which, is a sample.

my question is does this sample have 2 or more observations? or only one.

what does that mean by saying "a sample having 2 (or more) observations" in the scenario above.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw two balls, e.g. `[3,1]`, this is one possible state of your system and hence only a single observation. In your example, the number on ball 1 and the number on ball 2 are two distinct "features". A single observation (one data point) hence consists of values for both features.

Correspondingly, two (or more) observations in this scenario refer to two (or more) pairs of numbers.

Comment: would you please give an example of two pairs of numbers? e.g. [3,1] and [3,2]? are these two pairs of numbers A single observation? I am confused

Comment: it's the result of two independent draws, resulting, e.g., in `[3,1]` and `[2,3]`

Comment: I draw 2 times and get e.g. [3,1] and [2,3]. these are two independent draws, that's what I've already known. My question is, what is(are) the observation?

Comment: In my understanding, each draw (of two balls) is one observation.